# Manga/manhwa/manhua about a main character who lived in a different world with wild wolves for hundreds years

Tags: story-identification, manga

The main character lived in different world where he became the King/Alpha of the wolves' pack and fought with other animals for territory.  I think he was there for hundreds years before he returned back to Earth. They didn't believe him about what he said, because the portal that he came back from was weird or something.

The Earth was already connected to three different worlds and this was supposed to be the fourth, but they didn't believe him (don't remember why exactly).

He then started hunting monsters in some area where they spawned? Or maybe portal was there, I'm not sure. He became a hunter and got his license. I think he fought with some crazy guy who was C-rank and was known as a murderer, but no one dared to do anything.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: I think it was full color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this ***[The Druid of Seoul Station](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/hnp97ml/the-druid-of-seoul-station)***...?

From [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/manga/147489/The_Druid_of_Seoul_Station):

> What started out as an ordinary day turned upside down when an unknown catastrophe struck Earth, transporting Suho Park to a different planet. He eventually learns how to adapt and fight for his survival in this foreign world, but one day, just as suddenly as he was sucked into this new planet, Suho is pulled back to Earth. He quickly learns that return to life as he remembers it is no longer possible, as Earth is in constant battle with monsters who've managed to infiltrate the planet. How will Suho fight against the monsters attacking Earth, and will he be able to survive this time with his current skills?

It's a full colour manhwa, and has a protagonist who's isekaied to another world where he becomes part of a wolfpack, before returning to Earth hundreds of years later.

I've only skimmed the first few chapters, but I'll read through some more of it and see if I can match some more details.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you so much!